# jQuery - creating elements inside table

Tags: jquery

I am trying to dynamically create a Checkbox, Button & 2 Input boxes inside a table using jQuery. Below is my jQuery code, its creating the elements BUT not creating columns properly. What am I missing?

```
var contentTblOpen = "<table border='4'>";
        var contentTblClose = "</table>";
        var contentTrOpen = "<tr>";
        var contentTrClose = "</tr>";
        var contentTdOpen = "<td>";
        var contentTdClose = "</td>";


        $("#Quote" + id).after(

            contentTblOpen
        ).append(
            contentTrOpen
        ).append(
            contentTdOpen
        ).append(
        $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
            id: 'RL_' + rLCount + '__Delete'
        , name: 'RL[' + rLCount + '].Delete'
        , type: 'checkbox'
        , checked: false
        })
        .click(function (event) {
            var cbox = $(this)[0];
            alert(cbox.value);
        })
        ).append(
        $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
            id: 'Line' + rLCount
        , name: 'Line' + rLCount
        , value: 'Line' + rLCount
        , class: 'ClsrLButton'
        , type: 'button'
        })
        ).append(
            contentTdClose + contentTdOpen
        ).append(
        $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
            id: 'RL_' + rLCount + '__TextLine'
        , name: 'RL[' + rLCount + '].TextLine'
        , value: 'RL_' + rLCount + '__TextLine'
        , type: 'input'
        })
        ).append(
            contentTdClose + contentTdOpen
        ).append(
        $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
            id: 'RL_' + rLCount + '__Amount'
        , name: 'RL[' + rLCount + '].Amount'
        , value: 'RL[' + rLCount + '].Amount'
        , type: 'input'
        }).append(
            contentTdClose + contentTrClose + contentTblClose
        )
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing series of `append` create a long string (something like):

`'<table><tr><td><input id="RL_0__Delete" name="RL[0].Delete" type="checkbox">...'`

```
var newTable = contentTblOpen 
               + contentTrOpen
               + contentTdOpen
               + "<input " + "id='RL_" + rLCount + "__Delete'" + "type='checkbox' >"
```

and append this string.

BTW, manipulating DOM is quite slow, so if you create a string and append everything at one go you win few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks. I need a combination of string concatenation and creating elelemts (document.createElement("input")).attr...) because if I create a button with a class using string concatenation, further calls to jQuery using the class attribute is not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

The main pitfall here is that with each call to `.append()` the browser will create a valid DOM. So as soon as you insert a `<tr>` without a `</tr>` the browser will insert the `</tr>` for you and the result will be a valid DOM but it won't be what you originally intended.

Please check out strah's answer, it should help you.